# N_distinct by first value of variable

Tags: r, group-by, count

I have a column in my dataset that begins with 1 if the ID belongs to a manager and 2 if the ID belongs to a worker. I would like to count the total distinct number of ID's by location, and then the distinct number of managers only, by location. How would I alter this code in order for there to be a column of the total distinct ID's by location, and another column with only the managers (ID starts with 1) to show up in distinct and not the total number of ID's?

```
MANAGERS_BYSITE <- file %>%
group_by(LOCATIONID) %>%
summarise(n_distinct(ID))
colnames(MANAGERS_BYSITE) <- c("LOCATIONID", "UNIQUEID", 
"UNIQUEMANAGERS")
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
LOCATIONID   UNIQUEID    UNIQUEMANAGERS
01           3433532      6432
```

Where UNIQUEID is the number of distinct ID's by location and UNIQUEMANAGERS is the number of distinct managers by that same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new column (managerid) which has only Manager IDs i.e. it has id if it starts with 1 and otherwise it is NA.

The following code should give you what you are looking for.

> df %>% group_by(loc) %>% summarise(n_distinct(id),n_distinct(managerid)-1)

-1 since it will count NA as a unique value.

Comment: I think the main issue is I am not sure how to create the new column with only IDs that start with 1? If you could provide any insight on this that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In future please enter some example data that we can use to help you faster.

Here is my way (I am sure not the best or easiest way to do this) with some small sample code I created:

```
data <- data.frame(LOCATIONID=rep(1:3, 2),
                   ID=c("1_362711", "2_362181", "2_43289", "1_362711", "1_326173", "2_3261783"))

MANAGERS_BYSITE <- data %>%
    group_by(LOCATIONID) %>%
    summarise(UNIQUEID=n_distinct(ID)) %>%
    join(y = (filter(data, stri_sub(ID, 1, 1)=="1") %>%
              group_by(LOCATIONID) %>%
              summarise(UNIQUEMANAGERS=n_distinct(ID))), by="LOCATIONID")
```

This way you don't need to create any extra columns or rename anything afterwards.

Output:

```
   LOCATIONID UNIQUEID UNIQUEMANAGERS
       1         1           1
       2         2           1
       3         2           NA
```